# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' to 'NSString'

Tags: swift, string, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code `let Model = i.get("Model") as! String` I am using it from my firestore database. I am trying to make it search that. I tried it with other fields and it worked just not with some that were integers and Model when model in my database is a String. I get this error  `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7f851d873250) to 'NSString' (0x7fff86cf7118).`[image][image]

Comment: `let Model = (i.get("Model") as! NSNumber).stringValue` if I refer to the errror, but it's indeed strange for it to be a `NSNumber`. Could you print `i.get("Model")`?

Comment: This appears to be an internal issue, not associated with your code, just on the face of it. Clean the build folder and try again. If the issue persists, consider updating your Firebase dependencies (through SPM or CocoaPods) and try again. If it persists then try with a different document or the same document in a different project.

Comment: @trndjc It is still happening it is not happening to all of the data fields only for Model and some other ones (only really the integer ones but that makes sense). I just don't know why it is only happening to Model.

Comment: This appears to be some sort of bug, or glitch, in your project. If you create a brand new Xcode project and do nothing but add the Firestore dependencies and attempt to read this document and this field, does it happen?

Comment: @trndjc I don't think it is a glitch because it happened to the same code in another project. THE SAME EXACT ERROR!